# using javaw to run jars in batch files results in more than one java processes in process explorer - XYNTService

Tags: java, service, windows-services, batch-file, jvm

I have a somewhat strange issue. I have a java application that installs few services that run as Jars. Previously I used installed Java to run these Jars. There are four services and all will be instantiated from a single batch file with sequential call to each other. Something like this,

```
start %JAVA_HOME% commandtoruntjarfile
```

would work and all four services will run in the background and only one java.exe visible in process explorer. So I had another service installed as windows service which would start stop these services by calling the run bat or shutdown bat.

Now the customer requirement changed to using an internalized version of java. I extract java to a location, make our own environment variable name "ABC_HOME" and the required syntax in batch changes to

```
%ABC_HOME%\javaw commandtorunjarfile
```

When its run it works. but there is no stopping these. When I go to process explorer I see 4 java.exe running each for the four run commands in the batch file. If I stop the windows service all the four keep working. If I restart the windows service the number of java.exe in process explorer goes to eight and keeps going up until windows has had enough of it.

How do I get around it? I think the solution should be to have the one java process in process explorer but I cant seem to find any solution for that.

[EDIT]
The four sub services are actually XYNT processes. In the normal scenario it would be something like this
    [Process1]
    CommandLine = java -Xrs -DasService=yes -cp jarfiles
    WorkingDir = c: bin scache
    PauseStart = 1000
    PauseEnd = 1000
    UserInterface = No
    Restart = Yes

For using java from a specific location the following change was needed

```
CommandLine = %JAVA_PATH%\bin\java.exe -Xrs -DasService=yes -cp jarfiles
```

but this wouldn't work as it would not accept the path variable in XYNT.ini file. so I called a batch file here and in that batch file I used the above code. So here is what the change looks like,

```
CommandLine = batchfile.bat
```

and in batchfile.bat

```
%JAVA_PATH%\bin\java.exe -Xrs -DasService=yes -cp jarfiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, every Java program run on your system has its own virtual machine running, which means: one java.exe/javaw.exe per instance of your program.

I can not tell why it "worked" from your point of view with java.exe like you described first, but the behaviour you described for javaw.exe (having 4 java processes in the process explorer) would be what I'd have expected.

For me the question is not why you're seeing 4 vs. 1 java processes, but how you can start/stop the "services". Killing the Java VM externally doesn't seem a very good solution. I'd consider building some IPC into the Java services that allow you to gracefully terminate the processes.

Comment: You are correct. One cannot kill the JVM externally as it would be stupid and if that is what we did we would have done that for this problem as well. In previous case the graceful termination was working because the windows service and the four hidden services were all in the same process. So jvm wouldn't close until the windows service was stopped. But as that jvm closed the four other services running under the same JVM would also close. Since now these are different JVMs running under different process IDs closing one does not have any impact on the others.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what exactly you mean by "service". On Windows, there's the concept of a "Windows NT Service" which you can start/stop using the Services snapin. On Linux there are daemons. They have in common that both of them don't have a user interface and are not interactive. What are your "services"? You know that there are wrappers which allow you to run a java application as a Windows NT Service - would that be a valid solution to your problem?

Comment: So there are four services that run in the background and are instantiated from xynt service. This xynt service is controlled from a windows service which is just like another windows service that can be installed and is visible in windows services.

Comment: A quick read shows me that XYNTService is able to run more than one service, and has command line options to start/stop services. Which means that your "real" windows service would be able to control which services are started by calling XYNTService with correct command line options.

Comment: Yes. So i need to start four services in the XYNTService. They start fine but in 4 different JVMs thus XYNTService is unable to stop them unless I do a all java process kill kind of thing. When the Windows Service that is linked to this XYNT is restarted all the four services just get restarted and end up having 8 instead of 4 JVMs and this number keeps on increasing. I am going to try the Windows shell path concept and see if that helps. Thereby when I run the XYNT it will have the custom java path in its shell and hopefully then I won't need to give the full java path location.